# Randomly creating and positioning elements within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Using the code submitted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002985/randomly-creating-and-positioning-elements-exceeds-browser-window/22003220#22003220), how could I do a similar (if not the same) thing within the confines of a predefined div?

The code 2pha provided has variables for the width and height of where to render these objects, but I'm not sure how to actually position the "box" within which it is rendering them.

It is probably worth noting that I am an extreme beginner, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you're looking at the width and height of the entire window are determined, and used as bounds for all the random boxes:

```
var ww = $(window).width();
var wh = $(window).height();
```

If, instead, you want all your random boxes inside another `div` (I've given it the id `container`) you could just read the width and height of that box.

```
var ww = $("#container").width();
var wh = $("#container").height();
```

You would also want to append the random boxes to your container div, rather 
than the `body`.

```
for(var x=1;x<=numTickets;x++){
    $(ticket).appendTo("#container");
}
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var ticket="<div class='ticket'><p>Random<br />Box</p></div>";
    var numTickets=10;
    for(var x=1;x<=numTickets;x++){
        $(ticket).appendTo("#container");
    }
    // get container dimentions
    var ww = $("#container").width();
    var wh = $("#container").height();
    $(".ticket").each(function(i){
        var rotationNum=Math.round((Math.random()*360)+1);
        var rotation="rotate("+rotationNum+"deg)";
        var posx = Math.round(Math.random() * ww)-20;
        var posy = Math.round(Math.random() * wh)-20;
        $(this).css("top", posy + "px").css("left", posx + "px").css("transform",rotation).css("-ms-transform",rotation).css("-webkit-transform",rotation);
    });
```

```css
.ticket{
    position: absolute;
     background: #F90;
     padding: 7px 3px;
 }

#container{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    
</div>
```