# Creating specific images and placing them in random positions within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, random

[Using the code submitted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002985/randomly-creating-and-positioning-elements-exceeds-browser-window/22003220#22003220), how could I do a similar thing but with a specific number of several different images, rather than one image repeated x number of times.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ticket="<div class='ticket'><img src='http://samuelbar.net/images/baddie.png'></div>";
var numTickets=10;
for(var x=1;x<=numTickets;x++){
    $(ticket).appendTo("body");
}
// get window dimentions
var ww = $(window).width();
var wh = $(window).height();
$(".ticket").each(function(i){
    var posx = Math.round(Math.random() * ww)-20;
    var posy = Math.round(Math.random() * wh)-20;
    $(this).css("top", posy + "px").css("left", posx + "px")
});
});
```

I edited 2pha's code to get rid of rotation, since that's what I'm after, but I don't know I'd edit it to generate a specific set of images.

Here's [an edited Fiddle to show what I'm talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/29M54/61/)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: so do you want to use more than 1 image ??

Comment: Yeah, I aim to have like a set of 7 that each only appear once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need? (I changed only one image for the sake of saving time)
https://jsfiddle.net/9wuu4fph/

Basically, you can construct an array holding the 7 different images and then randomly select one each loop iteration, followed by its removal from the array (so it doesn't get picked again).

**The array** (better have the image url only, create dom element in loop):

```
var tickets = [
    "<div class='ticket'><img src='http://samuelbar.net/images/baddie.png'></div>",
    "<div class='ticket'><img src='http://samuelbar.net/images/baddies272.png'></div>",
    "<div class='ticket'><img src='http://samuelbar.net/images/baddie.png'></div>",
    "<div class='ticket'><img src='http://samuelbar.net/images/baddie.png'></div>",
    "<div class='ticket'><img src='http://samuelbar.net/images/baddie.png'></div>",
    "<div class='ticket'><img src='http://samuelbar.net/images/baddie.png'></div>",
    "<div class='ticket'><img src='http://samuelbar.net/images/baddie.png'></div>",
];
```

**The loop:**

```
// We need to retain original length, to run loop X times
var ticketsOriginalLength = tickets.length;

for (var x = 0; x < ticketsOriginalLength; x++) {
    // Use updated length, or else index out of bounds errors
    var rand = getRandomInt(0, tickets.length - 1);
    $(tickets[rand]).appendTo("body");
    // Remove image from array
    tickets.splice(rand, 1);
}
```

**'Random' function:**

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's perfect! Thanks so much :)